# Commission calculation using PHP

Tags: php, object-oriented

Task is to read file([input.csv](https://github.com/yusttas/commissions-calculator/blob/master/input.csv)) and calculate each operations commission depending of operation type(cash_in or cash_out).

I dont have any specific questions, just want overall feedback, like code structure, naming, readibilty, good practices.

Next step would be to write unit tests(still learning) so my code need to be testable. Is there any things I could improve for that. Like im calling static method (CurrencyConverter::convertToEur) in CashoutStrategy class.

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Paysera\Entities\Operation;
use Paysera\Repositories\InMemoryOperationRepository as OperationRepository;
use Paysera\Services\Commissions\CommissionCalculator;
use Paysera\Services\Readers\CsvReader;

$path=trim(fgets(STDIN)); 

$repository = new OperationRepository();
$reader = new CsvReader($path);
$data = $reader->getData();

$id = 1;
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $operation = new Operation();
    $operation->setId($id++);
    $operation->setDate($row[0]);
    $operation->setPersonId((int) $row[1]);
    $operation->setPersonType($row[2]);
    $operation->setName($row[3]);
    $operation->setAmount($row[4]);
    $operation->setCurrency($row[5]);
    $repository->add($operation);
}

$calculator = new CommissionCalculator($repository);
$results = $calculator->calculate();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    fwrite(STDOUT, $result);
    fwrite(STDOUT, "\n");
}
```

Operation.php

```
namespace Paysera\Entities;
class Operation
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $date;
    private $person_id;
    private $person_type;
    private $amount;
    private $currency;
    const CASH_OUT = 'cash_out';
    const CASH_IN = 'cash_in';

    public function setId(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setDate(string $date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }
    public function getDate(): string
    {
        return $this->date;
    }
    public function setPersonId(int $person_id)
    {
        $this->person_id = $person_id;
    }
    public function getPersonId(): int
    {
        return $this->person_id;
    }
    public function setPersonType(string $person_type)
    {
        $this->person_type = $person_type;
    }
    public function getPersonType(): string
    {
        return $this->person_type;
    }
    public function setAmount(string $amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }
    public function getAmount(): string
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
    public function setCurrency(string $currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }
    public function getCurrency(): string
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }
}
```

OperationRepository.php

```
namespace Paysera\Repositories;

interface OperationRepository
{
    public function getAll(): array;
    public function getPersonCashOutOperationsFromSameWeek(int $person_id, $date): array;
}
```

InMemoryOperationRepository.php

```
namespace Paysera\Repositories;
use Paysera\Entities\Operation;
use Paysera\Repositories\OperationRepository;

class InMemoryOperationRepository implements OperationRepository
{
    protected $operations;

    public function add(Operation $operation)
    {
        $this->operations[] = $operation;
    }

    public function getAll(): array
    {
        return $this->operations;
    }

    public function getPersonCashOutOperationsFromSameWeek(int $person_id, $date): array
    {
        $operations = [];
        $current_date = new \DateTime($date);
        $current_week = $current_date->format('W');
        foreach ($this->operations as $operation) {
            $operation_date = new \DateTime($operation->getDate());
            $operation_week = $operation_date->format('W');

            if ($operation->getPersonId() == $person_id && $operation->getName() == Operation::CASH_OUT) {
                if ($current_week == $operation_week && abs($current_date->diff($operation_date)->format('%R%a'))<=7) {
                    $operations[] = $operation;
                } else if ($current_week < $operation_week) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $operations;
    }
}
```

CommissionCalculator.php

```
namespace Paysera\Services\Commissions;

use Paysera\Entities\Operation;
use Paysera\Repositories\OperationRepository;
use Paysera\Services\Commissions\CashInStrategy;
use Paysera\Services\Commissions\CashOutStrategy;

class CommissionCalculator
{
    protected $operations;

    public function __construct(OperationRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    protected function getStrategy(Operation $operation): CommissionStrategy
    {
        $operation_name = $operation->getName();
        switch ($operation->getName()) {
            case Operation::CASH_IN:
                $strategy = new CashInStrategy($operation);
                break;
            case Operation::CASH_OUT:
                $strategy = new CashOutStrategy($operation, $this->repository);
                break;
            default:
                throw new \Exception("Unknown strategy: " . $operation_name);
                break;
        }
        return $strategy;
    }

    public function calculate(): array
    {
        $results = [];
        foreach ($this->repository->getAll() as $operation) {
            $calculator = $this->getStrategy($operation);
            $results[] = $this->format($calculator->calculate());
        }
        return $results;
    }

    protected function format($result): string
    {
        $rounded = ceil($result * 100) / 100;
        $formatted_result = number_format((float) $rounded, 2, '.', '');
        return $formatted_result;
    }
}
```

CommissionStrategy.php

```
namespace Paysera\Services\Commissions;

use Paysera\Entities\Operation;

abstract class CommissionStrategy
{
    protected $operation;

    public function __construct(Operation $operation)
    {
        $this->operation = $operation;
    }

    abstract public function calculate();
}
```

CashInStrategy.php

```
namespace Paysera\Services\Commissions;

use Paysera\Entities\Operation;
use Paysera\Services\Commissions\CommissionStrategy;

class CashInStrategy extends CommissionStrategy
{
    const COMMISSION_PERCENT = 0.03;
    const COMMISSION_MAX = 5;

    public function calculate(): float
    {
        $commission = $this->operation->getAmount() * self::COMMISSION_PERCENT / 100;
        if ($commission > self::COMMISSION_MAX) {
            return self::COMMISSION_MAX;
        }
        return $commission;
    }
}
```

CashOutStrategy.php

```
namespace Paysera\Services\Commissions;

use Paysera\Entities\Operation;
use Paysera\Repositories\OperationRepository;
use Paysera\Services\Commissions\CommissionStrategy;
use Paysera\Services\CurrencyConverter;

class CashOutStrategy extends CommissionStrategy
{
    const COMMISSION_PERCENT = 0.3;
    const COMMISSION_MIN_LEGAL = 0.50;
    const TIMES_PER_WEEK = 3;
    const AMOUNT_PER_WEEK = 1000;
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(Operation $operation, OperationRepository $repository)
    {
        parent::__construct($operation);
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function calculate(): float
    {
        $person_type = $this->operation->getPersonType();
        if ($person_type == 'natural') {
            $commission = $this->calculateForNaturalPerson();
        } else if ($person_type == 'legal') {
            $commission = $this->calculateForLegalPerson();
        }
        return (float) $commission;
    }

    protected function calculateForNaturalPerson(): float
    {
        $id = $this->operation->getId();
        $person_id = $this->operation->getPersonId();
        $current_date = $this->operation->getDate();
        $current_amount = CurrencyConverter::convertToEur($this->operation->getAmount(), $this->operation->getCurrency());
        $person_operations = $this->repository->getPersonCashOutOperationsFromSameWeek($person_id, $current_date);
        $times_per_week = 0;
        $amount_per_week = 0;
        $discount_id = null;
        foreach ($person_operations as $operation) {
            $times_per_week++;
            if ($times_per_week <= self::TIMES_PER_WEEK) {
                $amount_per_week += CurrencyConverter::convertToEur($operation->getAmount(), $operation->getCurrency());
            }
            if ($amount_per_week >= self::AMOUNT_PER_WEEK) {
                $discount_id = $operation->getId();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($discount_id)) {
            if ($id == $discount_id) {
                $current_amount = $amount_per_week - self::AMOUNT_PER_WEEK;
            } else if ($id < $discount_id) {
                $current_amount = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $current_amount = 0;
        }
        $commission = $current_amount * self::COMMISSION_PERCENT / 100;
        $converted = CurrencyConverter::convertEur($commission, $this->operation->getCurrency());
        return $converted;
    }

    protected function calculateForLegalPerson(): float
    {
        $commission = $this->operation->getAmount() * self::COMMISSION_PERCENT / 100;
        if ($commission < self::COMMISSION_MIN_LEGAL) {
            return self::COMMISSION_MIN_LEGAL;
        }
        return $commission;
    }
}
```

CurrencyConverter.php

```
namespace Paysera\Services;
class CurrencyConverter
{
    const EUR_CONVERSION = [
        'EUR' => 1,
        'USD' => 1.1497,
        'JPY' => 129.53,
    ];

    public static function convertEur($amount, $currency): float
    {
        $result = $amount * self::EUR_CONVERSION[$currency];
        return (float) $result;
    }

    public static function convertToEur($amount, $currency): float
    {
        $result = $amount / self::EUR_CONVERSION[$currency];
        return (float) $result;
    }
}
```

CsvReader.php

```
namespace Paysera\Services\Readers;

class CsvReader implements Reader
{
    private $file_path;
    private $delimeter;

    public function __construct(string $file_path, string $delimeter = '')
    {
        $this->setFilePath($file_path);
        $this->setDelimeter($delimeter);
    }

    public function setFilePath(string $file_path)
    {
        if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
            throw new \Exception('Wrong path');
        }
        $this->file_path = $file_path;
    }

    public function setDelimeter(string $delimeter)
    {
        if (empty($delimeter)) {
            $this->delimeter = ',';
        } else {
            $this->delimeter = $delimeter;
        }
    }

    public function getData(): array
    {
        $results = [];
        $row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen($this->file_path, "r")) !== false) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $this->delimeter)) !== false) {
                $num = count($data);
                $row++;
                for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    $results[] = explode($this->delimeter, $data[$c]);
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

Link to repository https://github.com/yusttas/commissions-calculator

Comment: Hey you need to post the code you want us to review on here, not a link to the github

Comment: Updated question with code

Comment: You could have left the link to your GitHub in the question. Also: A small sample file would be helpful for anyone who would actually want to check your code (don't assume it will be me...). Otherwise it's quite a dry exercise.

Comment: what do you mean dry exercise?

Comment: It would be nice if we could actually run the code, dive in, and 'get wet'. Without a sample CSV file we can't do that. Hence the 'dry exercise' analogy.

Comment: Found your GitHub link at the end of your question, and there's a sample CSV file there.